# How to turn on/off my laptop Bluetooth using C#.NET

Tags: c#, bluetooth

```
if (!BluetoothRadio.IsSupported)
{
   tbOutput.Text = "No Bluetooth Adapter found!!!";
} else
{
  if (BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode == RadioMode.PowerOff)
      BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode = RadioMode.Discoverable;
}
```

I want to turn on or off my laptop blutooth using C#.NET.

Comment: where did you actually take this code, what have you tried, did you read documentations about the topic?

Comment: i get this code from google and i have used 32feet.net dll files. I tried to turn on or off my laptop bluetooth from c# window form application but there is no fruitfull result came out

Comment: i read continuously article about my topic but there is no straight frwrd guide

Comment: @SyedFazalHussain I had the same problem with WIFI, but no one help me to suggest some code,How can we put some code without any idea how to do it.Its not a task like building a calculator.I think we need to work with hardware devices.Is there any solution in .net framework?

Comment: Do u have woriking code for enabling/disabling  wifi?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362927(v=vs.85).aspx) the answer may be BluetoothSetServiceState but I also can't find anything on BluetoothRadio within your code snippet in your post so you may want to make sure that it is supported and isn't causing any problems.