# how to enable Bluetooth of windows 10 laptop using c#.net

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-10

I have already find most of all the website related to this question but not getting a good answer that help me out

So please help me out in that case I really don't know how to enable Bluetooth turn on in windows 10 laptop C#.net

I am using Windows platform I am creating app for only windows laptop and i want to start Bluetooth using my app if Bluetooth is not started

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445591/how-to-turn-on-off-my-laptop-bluetooth-using-c-net

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the radio's using the following snippet if you're using the Universal Windows Platform

```
var result = await Radio.RequestAccessAsync();
if (result == RadioAccessStatus.Allowed)
{
     var bluetooth = (await Radio.GetRadiosAsync()).FirstOrDefault(radio radio.Kind == RadioKind.Bluetooth);
    if (bluetooth != null && bluetooth.State != RadioState.On)
    await bluetooth.SetStateAsync(RadioState.On);
}
```

but not knowing what platform you're using specifically there's no way to tell

Comment: I am very thankful to you to give me a answer but I am using Windows platform I am creating app for only windows laptop and i want to start bluetooth using my app if bluetooth is not started

Comment: what windows platform are you using? are you using windows presentation foundation, windows forms, or uwp?

Comment: thanks your reply ...i am using windows forms and i made this windows desktop application in windows 10.

Comment: you should takke a look at this link http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35775-serial-port-communication-in-c%23/

Comment: when i send request for radio but it gives me denied what i should do ? this error occurred on var "result = await Radio.RequestAccessAsync();"